# How to simply add ' and " to numeric values for height(inch) format?

Tags: mysql

I have a height field that contains two numeric values and I need to add ' and " at the end of each number to display the value as height(inch) format.
It seemed simple but couldn't find answers that I was looking for.

Height -> Height(inch)

72     ->   7'2"

65     ->   6'5"

68     ->   6'8"
.            .
.            .
.            .
.            .

Any suggestions? I am very new to sql and and would appreciate any help I can get!!

Comment: If the value I give you is 111, how can you tell if the value is 1'11" or 11'1"?

Comment: Good questions! But the height data set I am working with is consist of only two numeric value!

Comment: As long as both values are between 0-9, you could do `CAST(SUBSTRING([value],0,1) AS char(1)) + '''' + CAST(SUBSTRING([value],1,1) AS char(1)) + '"'`

Comment: Thanks so much! I had to tweak a little but it's exactly what I needed. Have a wonderful Friday!

Comment: What does 510 mean?  51'0"?

Comment: I would expect 72 -> 6'0".

Comment: I don't know about you, but for me if someone said  72 and I knew they were using the old imperial (British/American) system, I would immediately think 6'0 and not 7'2 (which is more likely - hint, I am the former, not the latter!). Why not convert to metric and store as such and then figure out how to do it the .other way .round - simpler , I'd say. Store as mm and then that might be easier? Lived in Paris for a few years - metric is **way** better **and** it's S.I.!

Answer (score 1):

```
mysql> select concat(LEFT(73, 1),'\'',SUBSTR(73, 2),'\"') converted;
+-----------+
| converted |
+-----------+
| 7'3"      |
+-----------+
```